# How to config Subversion authentication via Google Accounts?

Tags: svn, openid, redmine

I installed Redmine 1.3.x on Ubuntu server 12.04 with Subversion Integration
and installed Google Apps Login plugin for authentication user via google account.

However subversion only accepts user authentication via internal account of the Redmine

Now i want to configure Subversion authentication user via google account.

Comment: HAve you read the instructions at http://www.redmine.org/plugins/google_apps ?

Comment: yes, i have but can not fix this bug

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What did you do and what errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [mod_auth_openid FAQ](http://findingscience.com/mod_auth_openid/faq.html) it is not possible to configure openid authentication for SVN http access.

From the FAQ:

> Can I use mod_auth_openid to protect a dav share/my svn installation?
>
> No. Due to the distributed nature of the OpenID specification users
>   must be able to be redirected to an Identity Provider website to
>   authenticate themselves, and then be redirected back to the initial
>   resource they were attempting to view. Any software that requires
>   Basic HTTP Authentication (webdav, the svn client) cannot support such
>   a redirection. mod_auth_openid is designed specifically and solely for
>   protecting web based resources when being viewed from a standard web
>   browser.